# .htaccess redirect loop resulting from http --> https rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, heroku

Our code runs on two different servers. One has https enable and the other ("legacy") does not. We want to force https, but only on the SSL server.

I added the following code but it's causing a redirect loop.

```
#Force SSL for everyone but legacy production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !legacy\.site\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 #<--this also causes redirect loop
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} != https #<--this causes a 500 error!
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Below is the following (I don't believe this matters but I'm including it for completeness):

```
#gzip
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Why?

**Update**  The server is a Heroku Cedar app, which uses "piggy back" SSL: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/3/announcing_better_ssl_for_your_app

Comment: Won't this loop for as long as you're not going to `legacy.site.com`? Which virtual host is this in? What is the name of the site you're going to when getting the loop? `site.com`? `subdomain.site.com`?

Comment: Are there more rules in your .htaccess?

Comment: @arco444 I don't think so is should keep looping because it redirects to `https` which means the second condition should fail, right? The URL getting the loop is `new.site.com`

Comment: @anubhava I just updated the question with the rest of the rules.

Comment: Is it some CMS framework you're using?

Comment: @anubhava It is a web app built with Code Igniter, but not using any internal redirects/routing that I'm aware of. Also, the server is a Heroku Cedar app

Comment: Ah - Heroku... Does SSL get offloaded before you hit Apache? If so, Apache will never know if you're https or not.

Comment: @arco444 My understanding is that Heroku uses "pass through" SSL. I don't know how it works but it sounds like you're on the right track with thinking that the standard htaccess rules might not be compatible

Comment: @arco444 I just updated the question with a reference to Heroku's "Piggy-back" SSL.

Comment: @SDP I'll bet that your Apache server only receives http. That would explain the loop. Https will never be set to on, so you keep redirecting to it. It sounds like Heroku terminates SSL somewhere else, probably on an upstream load balancer and just sends you plain http behind that.

Comment: @arco444 That sounds like a reasonable hypothesis. Do you have any suggestion for how I can test this theory and/or fix the problem?

Comment: Any way you can get onto the box? Would suggest maybe checking for traffic on port 443. Also try removing your redirect to https, then browse to the site on https. From their documentation, that should work regardless. If it allows you to browse https the whole time you can be quite certain they're terminating SSL before traffic hits your app.

Comment: @arco444 I can definitely browse the site with https without the redirects, so I think we've confirmed that SSL terminates before traffic hits my app. Now what? Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Interesting update. I did an experiment using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} != https` and it didn't work, but instead of causing a redirect loop, it caused a single 500 error. Not sure what this tells us.

Comment: Most likely that it's bad syntax. Don't know how you get around this, it sounds like a Heroku issue so maybe contact their support. Maybe they'll send you a custom header indicating ssl status that you maybe able to inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to @anubhava and @arco444 for thoughtful comments...

It turns out the redirect loop I encountered resulted from the fact that SSL terminates upstream from Heroku Cedar stack apps. This means the last leg of the traffic is NEVER https, so normal techniques will redirect forever = redirect loop.

The way to solve this problem (on Heroku) is to add a RewriteCond for their special custom header `X-Forwarded-Proto`. So this works:

```
##Force SSL for everyone but legacy production
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !legacy\.site\.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Well done on getting this sorted - certainly an unenviable task!

Answer (score 1):

Your server may not be setting `HTTPS` variable. Try using `SERVER_PORT`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^legacy\.site\.com$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work either. Still redirect loop. I'll update the code in the question to show what I did.

Comment: Open Firebug and visit `http://domain.com/` in browser and see what redirects you get in `Net` tab.

Comment: Right but what are those redirects? Is it alternating between `http://` and `https://`?

Comment: No. After the first one (initiated by "other") they are all `https://new.site.com`

Comment: Same thing happens. Redirect loop.

Comment: Can you check your Apache version?

Comment: I don't own this heroku account, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: According to the response headers, the version of apache seems to be: `Apache/2.4.10`. Also, I got the owner to add me as a collaborator so I could run heroku commands... too bad their documentation is HORRIBLE

Comment: I have myself tried for hours to find some relevant Heroku documentation and didn't find anything to crack this problem.

Comment: The following summarizes the problem, and explains that Heroku adds it's own quirky headers to show the *original* scheme, but they don't appear to work as .htaccess rules: http://books.google.ca/books?id=GRI-9o6phYMC&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=heroku+https+between+load+balancer+and+app&source=bl&ots=oX7Lfe66kA&sig=apwUytSBGuyNi4qjUGhakEbLdtY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4YdGVLeEOurlsATX7YGwCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=heroku%20https%20between%20load%20balancer%20and%20app&f=false